# Generator syntax with 'flow' in MobX State Tree

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I have three actions in a MobX State Tree store: the first fetches data form the API, the second sends a POST request using the data from the API in the database, and the third takes the response and saves it to the store.

The store is comprised simply of a map of these data structures called Lists:

```
export const ListStore = types
  .model('ListStore', {
    lists: types.map(List),
  })
```

The first two actions to send the GET and POST requests work fine:

```
 .actions((self) => ({
    fetchTitles: flow(function* fetchTitles(params: Params) {
      const env = getStoreEnv(self);
      const { clients } = env;
      const browseParams: BrowseParams = {
        category: 'movies',
        imdb_score_min: params.filter.imdbFilterScore,
      };
      let browseResult;
      try {
        browseResult = yield clients.browseClient.fetch(browseParams);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch titles', error);
      }
      return browseResult.data.results.map((title) => title.uuid);
    }),
  }))
  .actions((self) => ({
    postList: flow(function* postList(params: Params) {
      const env = getStoreEnv(self);
      const { clients } = env;
      const titles = yield self.fetchTitles(params);
      return clients.listClient.create({
        name: params.name,
        titles,
        invites: params.invites,
        filter: params.filter,
      });
    }),
  }))
```

But when it comes to the third action, actually saving the List to the ListStore, no such luck. I've tried quite a few variations, but simply none of them work. Honestly I am not too familiar with generator syntax, and I even tried doing it without the generator. Here you can see my attempts:

```
createList: flow(function* createList(params: Params) {
  const env = getStoreEnv(self);
  const list = yield self.postList(params);
  console.log('list in createList', list.data);
  return self.lists.put(List.create({ ...list.data }, env));
  // return self.lists.set(list.id, list.data);
}),
createList: flow(function* createList(params: Params) {
  const list = yield self.postList(params);
  console.log('list in createList', list.data);
  yield self.lists.set(list.id, list.data);
}),
createList(params: Params) {
  return self.postList(params).then((list) => {
    console.log('list in createList', list.data);
    self.lists.set(list.id, list.data);
  });
},
createList: flow(function* createList(params: Params) {
  yield self.postList(params).then((list) => {
    console.log('list in createList', list.data);
    return self.lists.set(list.id, list.data);
  });
}),
```

I've tried with both `.set()` and `.put()`, but to no avail. I've also tried using `yield` and `return`...nothing seems to work. The data logged in `console.log('list in createList', list.data);` looks correct and matches the model (and if it didn't, wouldn't I get an error saying so?). No errors are logged to the console, it just silently fails.

If you can spot the error and see how this should be written, I will be extremely grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Code look fine to me (second version is the ideomatic way). But I am missing some context; how are you determing whether this works or not. What do you expect to see, and what did you observe. For examples do the console.logs run? Because if not, maybe the network request never finishes? etc. I recommend to create a reproduction in code sandbox

Comment: @mweststrate Glad to hear that the second version looks correct. Regarding the context, the logs to the console do work and do show the correct data, as far as I can tell (as I mentioned in the second to last paragraph). It's when I inspect the ListStore in other parts of the app that I see that it's empty.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like the error could be something completely different (like reading from the wrong store or something). Best create a code sandbox to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This helped me narrow down the issue -- it turns out that, contrary to what I said above, the data did not conform exactly to the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was not with the syntax: as you can see in the first comment by the maintainer of MST, the second version is correct.

The problem lies in the way the model (not shown here) was created.